# permission denied; error 70 ....Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

Having an odd problem when running a Word 2007 macro.

Background info: This particular macro uses an ActiveX control. This allows the user to grab client/address information from a database and populate into formatted fields of a Word document.

All of this has worked flawlessly for several years on 50+ user PCs in the office. Came into the office yesterday morning and suddenly it no longer works. Everyone gets the error 70 permission denied message.

For reference `sProgressPath = "p:\acts\"`

Here is part of the code:

```
Dim InFile As String

InFile = sFolderPath & "Results.txt"

'Delete results file if present

If Dir(InFile) <> "" Then
   Kill InFile
End If

'start an instance of progress by executing the batch file

Set objshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strBatFilePath = sProgressPath & "how2send.bat"

**objshell.Run strBatFilePath, 0**

Set objshell = Nothing
```

Comment: Either permissions on the folder containing the bat file have changed, or some policy setting is preventing the bat file from running.  Can you launch the bat file manually by double-clicking it?

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Can you manually delete "Results.txt"?

Comment: the error occurs at  objshell.Run strBatFilePath, 0

Comment: I can manually run the batch file which is located on the database server. The batch file creates results.txt which contains client names and address fields. My guess is some type of policy update is at fault.

Comment: @JeffinVA - seems like a question for your IT support.

Comment: Problem solved. Our McAfee AV/HIP is the guilty party. Thanks to everyone for the assistance!